# Bootstrap Button Loading State - Safari

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The code below produces the desired result in Chrome, Firefox, & IE but not in Safari. I have searched and found many solutions - including on here - yet I cannot get it to work and have copied and pasted the code - any thoughts?  I am using the latest jQuery & Bootstrap 2.2.1 - hence why I am not having to load a bootstrap-button.js because it's integrated in Bootstrap 2.2.1.

Thanks,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#buttonLoad').button();

    $('#buttonLoad').on('click', function () {
        $(this).button('loading')
     }) 
});
</script>


<button style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:5px; float:left" id="buttonLoad" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  data-loading-text="Loading...">Login<i style="margin-left:6px" class=" icon-share-alt"></i></button>
```

Comment: What's the desired result? What's different?

Comment: The desired result is for the text on the button to change and for it to gray out, in Safari neither of these things happen.  My example is at http://lstoolbox.com - as you can see the home button has that code on there and in Safari it doesn't work but it will in Firefox or Chrome or IE

Answer (score 0):

[image]Not able to test at the moment in Safari but I have used this and it works fine in Safari. Try selecting the element using a class instead of the ID and see if that fixes it.

-Image attached shows working example in Safari.

```
<button type="submit" role="button" runat="server" id="SignUpBtn" name="SignUpBtn" onclick="ValidateSignUpForm(); return false;" class="btn btn-primary" validationgroup="EmailBlast" data-loading-text="Saving..." causesvalidation="true"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Subscribe</button>

 <script>
    function ValidateSignUpForm() {
        //if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate('EmailBlast'))) {
        //    Page_ClientValidate();
        //}
        Page_ClientValidate('EmailBlast');
        if (Page_IsValid) {
            $('#SignUpBtn').button('loading');
            EmailSignUpCallback.PerformCallback();
            SignUpLoadingPanel.Show();
        }
    }
</script>
```